# Store data-value from select option with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have the below code which I have based off [this link](http://www.deardorffdigital.com/articles/html5-web-storage)

```
<select name="myselect" class="myselectClass" id="myselectID">
    <option data-value='{"comporder":"0"}' value="myval0">test 0</option>
    <option data-value='{"comporder":"1"}' value="myval1">test 1</option>
    <option data-value='{"comporder":"2"}' value="myval2">test 2</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" id="myinput" name="webStorageInput" />
<input type="submit" id="mysave" value="Save" />

<script type="text/javascript">   
var storedText = localStorage.getItem('webStorageTestInput');
var inputBox = document.getElementById("myinput");
var saveBtn = document.getElementById("mysave");
alert(storedText);

saveBtn.onclick = function(){
var valueToSave =inputBox.value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');

localStorage.setItem('webStorageTestInput',valueToSave);
};
</script>
```

See [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/dsrAV/)

I can store a value I input into local storage through an input field however I want the value I store to use the last option the user selected in my , eg if they selected test 1 their value would be 1.

I thought this was the best way to do this (using data-value) but it is not required I just don't want it to use the options value .

Another approach I tried was to just get the index of the option.

```
<select name="mySelect" class="myselectClass" id="mySelect">
    <option value="myval0">test 0</option>
    <option value="myval1">test 1</option>
    <option value="myval2">test 2</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="mysave" value="Save" />


<script>
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
var saveBtn = document.getElementById("mysave");


saveBtn.onclick = function(){
    alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " is " + y[x].text);
 };
</script>
```

But if I do this I get the below alert each time no matter what I click.

```
Index: 0 is test 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this, because you are using `jQuery`

```
$("#mysave").on('click', function(){
    var i = $("#mySelect").prop("selectedIndex");
    var t = $("#mySelect option:selected").text();
    alert("Index: " + i + " is " + t);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dsrAV/3/).